# Getting MulterError: Unexpected field when adding mutiple file in put request

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am working on uploading multiple files for my product. But when i am trying to make a put request with those files, i got an error from multer on runtime

```
MulterError: Unexpected field
    at wrappedFileFilter (G:\GIT\Mern_Eshop\back-end\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (G:\GIT\Mern_Eshop\back-end\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
    at Busboy.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Busboy.emit (G:\GIT\Mern_Eshop\back-end\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (G:\GIT\Mern_Eshop\back-end\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
    at PartStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (G:\GIT\Mern_Eshop\back-end\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
    at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at HeaderParser._finish (G:\GIT\Mern_Eshop\back-end\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:68:8)
    at SBMH.<anonymous> (G:\GIT\Mern_Eshop\back-end\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:40:12)
    at SBMH.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at SBMH._sbmh_feed (G:\GIT\Mern_Eshop\back-end\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:159:14)
    at SBMH.push (G:\GIT\Mern_Eshop\back-end\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:56:14)
    at HeaderParser.push (G:\GIT\Mern_Eshop\back-end\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:46:19)
    at Dicer._oninfo (G:\GIT\Mern_Eshop\back-end\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:197:25)
    at SBMH.<anonymous> (G:\GIT\Mern_Eshop\back-end\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:127:10)
```

**My code is here**

```
router.put(
    '/gallery-images/:id',
    uploadOptions.array('images', 10),
    async (req, res)=> {
        if(!mongoose.isValidObjectId(req.params.id)) {
            return res.status(400).send('Invalid Product Id')
        }
        const files = req.files;
        let imagesPaths = [];
        const basePath = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/public/uploads/`;

        if(files) {
            files.map(file =>{
                imagesPaths.push(`${basePath}${file.filename}`);
            })
        }

        const product = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.params.id,
            {
                images: imagesPaths
            },
            { new: true}
        )

        if(!product)
            return res.status(500).send('the gallery cannot be updated!')

        res.send(product);
    }
)
```

**Any advice appreciated on where to look ?**

Comment: Please add the request you're trying to send to the question, e.g. a `curl` represenation of it.

Answer (score 0):

This error generally occur when you are sending the name different on Images and using different multer configuration.

```
uploadOptions.array('images', 10) // check your are sending files with name 'images'
```

If the name is different, you should put that name instead.